# Looping a list through a column in webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-lists

If I'm expecting a page to display 5 offers, how would I tell webdriver to list all those 5 offers in a ul?

The Ul html code is

```
<ul id="more-load" class="product_list_widget pagination-centered" style="padding-top:15px;">
```

I think you would use

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='more-load']/ul/li")); 

for (WebElement element: allElements) {
      System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

but I'm not sure how to print each individual offer in the Ul and match the 5 offers expected to be displayed

**EDITED CODE**

never mind used this and worked

```
WebElement allElements = driver.findElement(By.id("more-load"));

    List<WebElement> liElements = allElements.findElements(By.tagName("li"));


    for (int i = 0; i < liElements.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(liElements.get(i).getText());
    }
```

however if I have a column on the left side, with ul = product categories, how would I loop it to go through each individual link text and preform the same function

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your 5 offers are as below:

```
Offer1
Offer2
Offer3
Offer4
Offer5
```

now your approach is correct till for loop:

then you can do something like :

```
String offerString = Offer1 + " " + Offer2 + " " +  Offer3 + " " +  Offer4 + " " + Offer5;

for (WebElement element: allElements) {
      if(offerString.contains(element.getText()){

        System.out.println("Offer item is: " + element.getText());

      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stick with your original attempt, except change the line:

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='more-load']/ul/li"));
```

to

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='more-load']/li"));
```

Answer (score 0):

using java8:

```
List<String> offers =  driver
            .findElements(By.cssSelector("#more-load li"))
            .stream()
            .map(WebElement::getText)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and you can assert *offers.size()* to have some expected value by any assert library

To get linked text elements in UL you can use next selector:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul a"))
```